# How to check if a a variable contains both alphabets and numbers

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to make a check in a shell script on linux which exits if `STR` contains "only alphabets" or contains "only numbers". it should pass if `STR` contains both numbers and alphabets. And not contain special characters.

I am trying it with something like this but it works only partially.

```
#!/bin/sh

STR=$1

if [[ ! $STR =~ ^[[:alnum:]]*[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]*$ ]]; then
    echo "The input must contain both digits and alphabets like abc123"
    exit 1
fi

echo "Success"
exit 0
```

The check works partially, that is if `STR` contains only numbers. But does not work if `STR` contains all alphabets. I want `exit 1` to not execute only if `STR` contains both alphabets and numbers like `abc123` or `ABC123`.

The check fails if `STR` contains `abc`.

How can I make the check work when `STR` contains `abc` only as well as when `STR` contains `123` only?

Comment: pro tip, don't actually name your script "test", unless you're careful about how you invoke it :)

Comment: note that the "alnum" includes "alpha" and "numerics" so if you really want to see a number, "alnum" isn't the best choice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex `^[[:alnum:]]*[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]*$` doesn't check for numbers separately, since `[:alnum:]` matches also letters. `[:alpha:]` should be a subset of `[:alnum:]`, so the pattern matches any string that is all alphanumerics, with at least one letter.

(Assuming the usual greedy matching, if the input is `abcd`, then the `abc` will be matched by `[[:alnum:]]*`, the final `d` will be matched by `[[:alpha:]]` and the last `[[:alnum:]]*` will not (need to) match anything.)

If you want to check that the string contains at least one letter and one digit, it's easier to separate that to two tests, i.e. test for `[[:alpha:]]` and `[[:digit:]]`:

```
if [[ $str =~ [[:alpha:]] && $str =~ [[:digit:]] ]]; then
    echo "contains a letter and a digit"
```

If you also want to reject strings that contain anything else (like punctuation), add a check for that:

```
if [[ $str =~ [[:alpha:]] && $str =~ [[:digit:]] && ! $str =~ [^[:alnum:]] ]]; then
    echo "contains a letter and a digit, but no non-alphanumerics"
```

To find the failing cases, invert the whole test with a `!` at the start (`if ! [[ ...`).

<sub>(To do that with one regex, you could use something like this:

`^([[:alnum:]]*[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]*[[:digit:]][[:alnum:]]*|[[:alnum:]]*[[:digit:]][[:alnum:]]*[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]*)$` 
but that's a bit horrible)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use complicated regular expressions here. You have two conditions, so use two tests:

```
if [[ $str == *[[:digit:]]* ]] &&
   [[ $str == *[[:alpha:]]* ]]
then
    printf '"%s" contains both letters and digits\n' "$str"
else
    printf '"%s" lacks either letters or digits\n' "$str"
fi
```

You also say something about "special characters" but you don't specify what these are. Assuming you mean characters matched by `[[:punct:]]`, and that you *don't* want these in the string, you could use

```
if [[ $str == *[[:digit:]]* ]] &&
   [[ $str == *[[:alpha:]]* ]] &&
   [[ $str != *[[:punct:]]* ]]
then
    printf '"%s" contains both letters and digits, and no specials\n' "$str"
else
    printf '"%s" lacks either letters or digits, or contains specials\n' "$str"
fi
```

`[[:punct:]]` would match any one of the characters in the string

```
!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make it simpler. Separate the question in two:

```
...
if [[ $STR =~ ([a-zA-Z]+) && $STR =~ ([0-9]+) ]]; then 
...
```

Comment: You are missing the not statement that is `!`. The not clause is important for me here to understand how this works

Comment: Figured out the not . `if [[ !($STR =~ ([a-zA-Z]+) && $STR =~ ([0-9]+)) ]]; then` it should be then

Comment: As far as I understand your question, you do NOT need the "not". The "if" I posted means: "do I have any letter here (normal or caps)? ... and also do I have any number here?" which is exaclty what you wrote in the description: "I want exit 1 ... only if STR contains both alphabets and numbers"

Comment: Actually, if you put that "not", you will destroy the logic.